colab files txt upload
I am using Colab. I need to upload some txt, so I can work with them. How can I do it?
After I do it, I expect to tokenize my text, so I can make tri-grams with them. If you can help to solve this problem too, I would be very thankful.

You will have to first upload your file to Colab:

If your file is locally stored on your computer, you will want to click on the folder icon on the vertical navigation bar on the leftmost side of your screen in Colab. Then, a button to upload files will be visible (the first one under the heading files)
If you have the file in your Google Drive, you might want to mount your drive to Colab. In doing so, you will gain access to all other files you have uploaded there (view this for further help in this matter)

Either way, once your file is uploaded to Colab, you will be able to access it as any other file on your local computer.
